# increase Cardboard performance up to 60 Fps

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

i am working on Architectural VR and i try to increase performance of the app by reducing display to render only what is visible trough the lenses and not what is outside near black border, all is performed : no light, no shadow, all lighmapped, occlusion ok, texture atlas ok ...i tried to modify the stereo scale screen but it seam like cardboard profile replace my setting by it own ... any idea ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Might be obvious, but...

- Have you tried to assess the performance issue using the unity profiler?
- What is the max number of draw calls?
- Make sure you are batching static items and that something is not breaking the static of dynamic batching.

hth.

J.

Comment: All is baked, occlusion + texture Atlas + static batching = 140 DrawCall, i think i have all optimized to the max possibility, the only next solution for me is to limit the rendering to what is realy visible trough lenses, but i dont no haw to make it

Comment: Is that a 140 draw calls in the editor? If so, keep in mind that this might double in VR.

Comment: I just checked and we try to keep draw calls bellow a 100. I've noticed that above 60, performance will vary greatly. On our Gear VR demos, running on Galaxy S6 phones, 100 was the max.

Comment: All my meshes are reduced to the minimum, but my question is how to reduce the display to only lenses visibility, can i try a camera mask or another solution ?

Comment: Have you looked at Occlusion Culling? http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html